# 60-year old dad passes out after 1/2 an hour of badminton

Tags: health-risk

My dad is 60 years old. I have never played any kind of sports for 30 years. 
However, he's working with geography and sometimes (maybe a week per month) he has to hike in the jungle as a part of his job.

Recently, a heart doctor prescribed medication for him. He now takes a heart pill every morning.

Today, he told me he wants to play badminton with me. This is the 1st time he played sports. So we played for 30 minutes. Then suddenly he felt tired and he sat down. Then, right at that time, I saw he fell asleep. I tried to call him but he didn't wake up. So I rushed out and call an ambulance, but my dad suddenly woke up.

He just passed out for 5 minutes. He told me that his doctor said he should do the walking exercise only.

My question is that "Is badminton too much for 60-year old person?"

And "What should I do now?"

- Tell him to stop playing badminton
- Tell him to do the walking exercise only

I am very worried for him. I thought he could have a stroke. I thought since he took the heart pills everyday, that could help him recover.

Comment: If he hasn't already, he needs to see a cardiologist and have a stress test.

Answer (score 2):

Badmintion is not inherently "too much" for a 60-year old male.

However, your father has a known heart condition and apparently has not exerted himself in sports before this event. I generally agree with the MD's suggestion. If your father wants to be more physically active than he currently is, he should speak with his doctor who knows all of his medical conditions -- my advice would be very different if he has congestive heart failure or another cardiac disorder such as dysrhythmias.

In turn, you should support the doctors recommendations. Push the walking; resist the badminton.

But be encouraged that he did not have a stroke (by definition he could not have had one). I cannot say with any certainty, but my best guess would be his blood pressure dropped a little too low and his body did responded by passing out to reestablish an appropriate oxygen flow to his brain.

Comment: so my dad didn't have a minor stroke? he just had blood pressure problem? but stroke is cos the blood does go go into the brain?

Comment: That is likely, but as the admins advised you'll only know for sure if you contact a medical professional in person and have your dad checked out. I said he did not have a stroke because it sounds like he did not have any lasting effects after his incident. Stroke by definition have to have symptoms >24hrs after the event. Therefore, it is most likely a drop in blood pressure. A stroke is not simply blood not getting to the brain. It is an acute loss of blood flow to a specific place in the brain usually caused by a blood clot blocking an artery.